# Xamarin.Forms - XamlParseException - tk:TKCustomMap not found in xmlns clr-namespace

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a TKCustomMap show up on an iOS emulator, but it keeps throwing the mentioned XamlParseException. I've been hammering my head on this for a while.  Still new to Xamarin and would appreciate some insights.  I just want to get this loaded so I can move on to ViewModels.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:TK.CustomMap;assembly=TK.CustomMap" x:Class="pop.MapPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <tk:TKCustomMap MapRegion="{Binding MapRegion}"
            IsShowingUser="{Binding IsShowingUser}"
            IsClusteringEnabled="{Binding IsClusteringEnabled}"
            Pins="{Binding Pins}"
            PinSelectedCommand="{Binding PinSelectedCommand}"
            PinDragEndCommand="{Binding PinDragEndCommand}"
            Routes="{Binding Routes}"
            RouteClickedCommand="{Binding RouteClickedCommand}"
            Polylines="{Binding Polylines}"
            Polygons="{Binding Polygons}"
            Circles="{Binding Circles}"
            TilesUrlOptions="{Binding TileOptions}"
            MapFunctions="{Binding MapFunctions}"
            SelectedPin="{Binding SelectedPin}"
            MapClickedCommand="{Binding MapClickedCommand}"
            MapLongPressCommand="{Binding MapLongPressCommand}"
            CalloutClickedCommand="{Binding CalloutClickedCommand}" />
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and the cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TK.CustomMap;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace pop
{
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Can anybody see what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

-T

Comment: Did you initialise the library in your android and iOS projects?

Comment: @EvZ  I have the package installed in the Solution for each platform.  As far as I understand according to https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/tree/Development/docs Android is the only platform that needs hardcoded intialization.  I'm trying to get iOS to work right now.  Thank you for your response